# How to change series legend text color in HighChart chart?

Tags: javascript, charts, highcharts

http://jsfiddle.net/n0mq739a/

[image]

I'm trying to change the series legend text color from black, to anything besides black:

```
$(function () {
$('#container').highcharts({

    legend: {
        color: '#FF0000',
        backgroundColor: '#FCFFC5'
    },

    xAxis: {
        categories: ['Jan', 'Feb', 'Mar', 'Apr', 'May', 'Jun', 'Jul', 'Aug', 'Sep', 'Oct', 'Nov', 'Dec']
    },

    series: [{
        data: [29.9, 71.5, 106.4, 129.2, 144.0, 176.0, 135.6, 148.5, 216.4, 194.1, 95.6, 54.4]
    }]
});
```

});

This is all I found on the legend in the HighCharts docs, is there another way to change that color?

http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#legend

Comment: @praguan hmm Quarterly and Goal are still colored black?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Here we go:

You need to specify itemStyle. e.g.

```
itemStyle:{'font-size':'30px'}
```

Depending on the css you want to use, you may also have to set 'useHTML'. From the documentation:

```
Using HTML allows for advanced formatting, images and reliable bi-directional text rendering.
```

Here is an example: http://jsfiddle.net/kHzr9/

Hope  it helps;)

Comment: Thanks! So just adding here for others, how I changed it in my actual app: `vm.config.options.legend.itemStyle.color = '#fff';`